# SWF advertisements through VAST Tag not played in JW player

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, flash, jwplayer

I configure Advertisement through VAST tag using jwplayer like.

```
$(document).ready(function(){
var playerInstance = jwplayer("player1");
playerInstance.setup({
    file: 'https://d150hyw1dtprld.cloudfront.net/videos/HP_VideoTest_NoPostRoll_v2_720p.mp4',
    width: "100%",
    displaytitle: false,
    controls: false,
    primary: 'flash',
    mute:'false',
    autostart: true,
    advertising: {
          client: "vast",
          tag: 'http://ads.adaptv.advertising.com/a/h/DLhbzlB+8BBfoyyx+Qo7i7Bx_Mpt2nNJbie4rwz4DHkL4tzFA61JtQ==?cb=${cachebreaker}&pageUrl=${embeddingPageUrl}&description=${description}&duration=${duration}&id=${id}&keywords=${keywords}&title=${title}&url=${videourl}&eov=eov&width=${width}&height=${height}&videourl=${videourl}&duration=${duration}&br_i=ad&context=${context.homepage}&adap_uid=7924494155751153126'
        }
});
});
```

The above SWF advertisement not played. only Primary Video (File) only plays. How can i Fix that??

Answer (score 1):

It seems like there is a problem with [the VAST file representing the advertisement you linked to in your code snippet](http://ads.adaptv.advertising.com/a/h/DLhbzlB+8BBfoyyx+Qo7i7Bx_Mpt2nNJbie4rwz4DHkL4tzFA61JtQ==?cb=$%7Bcachebreaker%7D&pageUrl=$%7BembeddingPageUrl%7D&description=$%7Bdescription%7D&duration=$%7Bduration%7D&id=$%7Bid%7D&keywords=$%7Bkeywords%7D&title=$%7Btitle%7D&url=$%7Bvideourl%7D&eov=eov&width=$%7Bwidth%7D&height=$%7Bheight%7D&videourl=$%7Bvideourl%7D&duration=$%7Bduration%7D&br_i=ad&context=$%7Bcontext.homepage%7D&adap_uid=7924494155751153126)—when I paste it into [Google's VAST Inspector](https://developers.google.com/interactive-media-ads/docs/sdks/html5/vastinspector), I get this error:

> (4:29:36 PM) Ad error: AdError 901: An unexpected error occurred within the VPAID creative. Refer to the inner error for more info. Caused by: Error: Error: No ad found in ad tag response

In the advertisement, there is a single `<MediaFile>` tag:

```
 <MediaFiles>
 <MediaFile delivery="progressive" width="400" height="300" type="application/x-shockwave-flash" apiFramework="VPAID">
 <![CDATA[
http://redir.adap.tv/redir/client/VPAIDClient.swf?adTagUrl=http%3A%2F%2Fads.adaptv.advertising.com%2Fa%2Fh%2FDLhbzlB%2B8BBfoyyx%2BQo7i7Bx_Mpt2nNJbie4rwz4DHkL4tzFA61JtQ%3D%3D%3Fcb%3D%24%7Bcachebreaker%7D%26pageUrl%3D%24%7BembeddingPageUrl%7D%26description%3D%24%7Bdescription%7D%26duration%3D%24%7Bduration%7D%26id%3D%24%7Bid%7D%26keywords%3D%24%7Bkeywords%7D%26title%3D%24%7Btitle%7D%26url%3D%24%7Bvideourl%7D%26eov%3Deov%26width%3D%24%7Bwidth%7D%26height%3D%24%7Bheight%7D%26videourl%3D%24%7Bvideourl%7D%26duration%3D%24%7Bduration%7D%26br_i%3Dad%26context%3D%24%7Bcontext.homepage%7D%26adap_uid%3D7924494155751153126%26a.cluster%3D0%26a.pvt%3D0&companionId=&cpmPassback=&placementId=266469&orgId=5047&injectCompanionDummy=&pauseOnClick=&d.vw=&d.app=
]]>
</MediaFile>
</MediaFiles>
```

The query param `adTagUrl` has this as its value:

```
http://ads.adaptv.advertising.com/a/h/DLhbzlB+8BBfoyyx+Qo7i7Bx_Mpt2nNJbie4rwz4DHkL4tzFA61JtQ==?cb=${cachebreaker}&pageUrl=${embeddingPageUrl}&description=${description}&duration=${duration}&id=${id}&keywords=${keywords}&title=${title}&url=${videourl}&eov=eov&width=${width}&height=${height}&videourl=${videourl}&duration=${duration}&br_i=ad&context=${context.homepage}&adap_uid=7924494155751153126&a.cluster=0&a.pvt=0&companionId=&cpmPassback=&placementId=266469&orgId=5047&injectCompanionDummy=&pauseOnClick=&d.vw=&d.app=
```

which seems like it's circling back to the same VAST file as the one you linked to. So it really just seems like you have a bad VAST tag here.